# Can I use Git to pull from server 1 and push to GitHub from desktop 1?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm trying to pull files from my hosted website and push the files to a project on GitHub, so I can work on them there. Here's what I'm looking to do on my laptop using [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway):

```
git pull https://www.example.com push https://github.com/account-name/main-website
```

Is this even possible, and if so, what would I need to do?

<sub>I am a total newbie here concerning Git and GitHub, so please bear with me. I have been researching, but I can't find what I need. I don't even know if it's possible, but I would think it would be.</sub>

Comment: On Windows, presumably?

Comment: Thanks.  It doesn't have to be from Windows.  Preferably from my webserver hosted on Apache server to my project on GitHub.  I copy the site to GitHub, then manage the content on GitHub and then push updates to the server.  I consider the hosted website a production server, so I really don't want to get editing directly, although I always back out any changes with FTP.

Answer (score 1):

Git deals in *commits*.  A `git pull` command is just shorthand for running two other Git commands:

1. `git fetch`, which *gets* commits; then, provided that succeeds,
2. one of (normally) two other Git commands that will help you integrate the retrieved commit(s) into your current branch.

A `git push` command *sends* commits.

Git doesn't exactly have *files*.  It has only the commits.  (The *commits* then have files inside them, as if they were each an archive containing every file.)  So you don't need `git pull` at all here, to transfer commits from a repository on Server 1 to a different repository on GitHub.  You just need `git fetch` and `git push`.

Note that when using `git fetch`, you get their *commits*, but you don't get their *branches* (branch names, to be precise).  Each Git repository has *its own* branch names.  Your repository has *your* branch names, not someone else's.  Git *commits* each have a unique number—a *hash ID* or *object ID*—so it's OK to share commits, because any commits you make will have a unique number, different from any other commit anyone else made.  But it's not exactly OK to share branch names, because a branch name holds just *one* commit hash ID, and if you made a new commit of your own, and they made a new commit of their own, one name won't suffice here.  So `git fetch` takes their *branch* names and renames them to become your *remote-tracking* names: their `develop` becomes, for instance, your `origin/develop`.  This assumes you get hold of their Git under the name `origin`—that's the standard name that `git clone` sets up to remember the URL you used at `git clone` time.

Should you want the GitHub repository to create or update *its* branch name `develop` based on the `server1-remote/develop` you get by copying commits from the Server-1 repository's `develop`, you might do this:

```
git fetch server1-remote develop
git push github-remote server1-remote/develop:develop
```

The `git fetch` command means:

- look up the name `server1-remote` to get a URL for the Server-1 repository;
- contact the Git software at that URL to connect up a Git to that repository;
- have them list out all their branch names and commit hash IDs; and
- get me whatever I need to update from their `develop`, remembering it as `server1-remote/develop`.

The name `server1-remote` is the name we gave to `git fetch`.  We limited this particular fetch to fetching *only* `develop`, but it often makes more sense to just get everything: this cheapens the cost of calling up their Git (which is generally pretty large) vs obtaining new commits from them (generally pretty small, if they don't normally have a lot of new stuff).  It's more expensive to run six `git fetch`-es, to update six branches / remote-tracking-names, than it is to run one `git fetch` that updates all six at once.

The `git push` step uses the remote name `github-remote` to call up Git software at a (presumably different) URL.  Whatever Git answers the Internet Telephone at that URL, you then hand over to it any commits that are new to it from your own `server1-remote/develop` (which has all the commits that are on server1's `develop` thanks to the fetch that just finished).  Then you ask, politely, that they create or update their own `develop` to remember the commits that end at the most recent such commit.  And that's all you had to do, provided:

- the fetch works;
- the push works (that they accept the new commits); and
- you've already set up these two *remote* names with the correct URLs.

Use different remote names if you like: these names are purely up to you.  The default `origin` name is fine but can only be used for *one* of these two URLs, and you need two names.  Use:

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```

(replace the `<name>` and `<url>` parts with the names and URLs you want) to add new remotes to some existing Git repository.  Use `git remote set-url` to change the URL associated with an existing remote.  Again, a *remote* is just a short name for a URL; by having two, you enable your Git to contact two other Gits and work with those repositories.

Note that if you do not want the *exact same commits* (with same hash IDs, snapshots, and commit metadata) in both remote repositories, you will have to take the *commits* you get from Server 1 and use those to make new and different commits to send to GitHub.  This is a much more involved process.